# Check Checkbox from the Same Row as an Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check the checkbox next to each html row if the select dropdown in the same row has something selected. Here is my html code and script. Can someone please point out what's wrong?

```
<tr>
    <td>Sohail Abbasi</td>
    <td>N&amp;S</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2013-01-03</td>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>09:21</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
    <select class="form-control" name="duty_status[3]">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
        <option value="2">Short Leave</option><option value="5">OD</option>
    </select>                            
    </td>
    <td><input class="form-control" name="user_comments[3]" type="text"></td>
    <td>
        <input name="submit[]" type="checkbox" value="3">                
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#SelectFilled').click(function($e)
{
    var elements=$('select[name^=duty_status]');
    var checkboxes=new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        if(elements[i].value)
        {
            var parent=elements[i].parentNode.parentNode;
            checkboxes[checkboxes.length]=parent.lastChild.firstChild;
         }
    }
    for (var j=0; j<checkboxes.length; j++) {
        checkboxes[j].checked=true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please give us some more example.. I don't quite understand what you want.. Sorry..

Comment: What is `#SelectFilled`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplfy your traversal code and make it far easier to read by using jQuery methods:

```
$('select[name^=duty_status]').each(function(){
   if( this.value === VALUE_I_WANT ){ /* not sure where this value comes from */
     $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
   } 
});
```

This code is based on the existing click handler triggering it. The goals in question are not very clear

Comment: Thanks!. It worked :) I just want to check if a valid value has been selected.That's All

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('td > select').on('change', function() {
        var chk = $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox');
        chk.prop('checked', this.selectedIndex !== 0 );            
    })
    .change();
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldtv8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Below code should works:

```
$('select[name^=duty_status]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() != ""){ //better put some value on the first option..
         $(this).parents("tr").find(":checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    }else{
         $(this).parents("tr").find(":checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```